# Why this CSS3 transition on height does not work

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have been working in an accordion, but for some odd reason the following code:

```
<style>
    .collapse {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: height .35s ease;
    -o-transition: height .35s ease;
    transition: height .35s ease;
    }
    .collapse.in {
    height: auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="accordion">
    <div class="something">
        <a class="" >Accordion Pane 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"> content </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$('.something').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.accordion-body').toggleClass('in');

})


</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvdXK/

doesn't seem to work. The height doesn't animate. And i dont know why.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need to set a specific height instead of `auto` for the transition to happen on height.

```
.collapse {
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 1.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 1.35s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1.35s ease;
    transition: height 1.35s ease;
    background-color: #cecece;
}
.collapse.in {
    height: 200px; /*Set the height here*/
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ht6R/)**

Or another option transition on max-height, like a max-height that is near impossible.

```
.collapse {
    max-height:0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #cecece;
}
.collapse.in {
    max-height:1000px;
}
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/nheup/)**

Here is a quote from [this page](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions):

> Transitioning gradients:
>   Not every CSS property can be transitioned, and the basic rule is that you can only transition through absolute values. For example, you can’t transition between a height of 0px to auto. The browser can’t calculate the intermediate transition values, so the property change is instant.

Comment: @MariaZ i think it is a limitation on auto height, how about transitioning on max-height? give a max-height something maximum..

Comment: @MariaZ Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nheup/ Its a limitation animating on height auto.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move as much of that CSS over to JQuery to truly control the animation: (You've got `animate-body` inside `animate-inner` and I think you've over complicated things.

```
$(".something").click(function () {
    $("this").nextUntil('.accordion-inner').animate({
        duration: 350,
        specialEase: {
            height: "easeInBounce"
        }
    }, {
        duration: 350,
        specialEasing: {
            height: "easeOutBounce"
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

height attribute should be define complusary, to make the smooth  page transition to work form very first. could even be of 0px. but must not be auto or max-height as 0px.