# Drop down menu effects

Tags: javascript, css

I have this drop down menu that appears when a button is clicked and disappears when clicked again. I'm wondering how to make the menu disappear from the bottom up, instead of just instantly disappear. I'm not asking for the exact code, just need pointed in the right direction. Thank you.

```
let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".mobile-icon");
console.log(nav);
icon.addEventListener("click", showMenu);

function showMenu() {
if (nav.style.display == "none"){
nav.style.display = "block";
} else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
}

}
```

Comment: If you are toddling the `display` property this is not possible. Sounds like you need to animate the height. Jquery have `slideToggle` if I recall correctly.

Comment: It would probably be best to create a css class like this: `.slideUp { height: 0; overflow: hidden; transistion: height 300ms ease; }` then toggle that class in javascript. You would actually probably have to have that as your default styles actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to create a class that sets the hight of the menu to 0px and then toggle this on and off using JavaScript.

I have created a small mockup in JSFiddle with some comments on the important parts.

Link to JSFiddle is - https://jsfiddle.net/gmuz2m98/

Here is the code though:

HTML -

```
<button> Hide/Show </button>

<ul>
  <li> Link 1 </li>
  <li> Link 2 </li>
  <li> Link 3 </li>
  <li> Link 4 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS -

```
ul {
  /* Give the ul a transition to run smoothly */
  transition: all .5s;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:20px 0px;
  background-color:#D6D6D6;

  /* Make sure overflow is hidden so when the hight is droped to 0px the li elements stay hidden */
  overflow:hidden;

  /* Give the ul a default hight to revert to, without this the transiton won't work */
  height:160px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* This is the class that will be added with JavaScript */
.hide {
  height:0px;
}
```

JS -

```
// Assign the ul and the button to a variable
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
        btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

// Create a function that lets the class 'hide' be toggled on and off the ul
function dropDown(){
    ul.classList.toggle('hide');
}

// Assign the function to the button with an EventListener
btn.addEventListener('click',dropDown,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, you cannot use `transition` for `height` property hence we use `max-height`. The problem is we need to set height in `px` for this solution to work, hence please use this workaround and test!

```js
let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".mobile-icon");
icon.addEventListener("click", showMenu);
nav.querySelector("ul").style.margin = "16px 0px";
nav.style.maxHeight = nav.querySelector("ul").clientHeight + 32 + "px";
function showMenu() {
  nav.classList.toggle("hideThis");
}
```

```css
nav{
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
nav.hideThis{
  max-height:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="mobile-icon">toggle</button>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions. Both above work perfectly.

Comment: I'm just curious. I've only been learning for about  month. Why can't you just change nav.style.height from 0px to auto when the button is clicked. It displays and hides the drop menu but ignores the transition.

Comment: @JohnAuer Transitioning gradients: Not every CSS property can be transitioned, and the basic rule is that you can only transition through absolute values. For example, you can’t transition between a height of 0px to auto. The browser can’t calculate the intermediate transition values, so the property change is instant. Refer [here](https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions) from the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341546/why-this-css3-transition-on-height-does-not-work)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses @Naren Murali. Last question.....Why does

Comment: function showMenu() {
 if (nav.style.height === "0px"){
 nav.style.height = "450px";
 } else {
  nav.style.height = "0px";
 }
}

Comment: only worked after second time I click the button even thought the height is set to 0px in css.

Comment: @JohnAuer Sorry, I do not have access to the code you are talking about, just do `console.log(nav.style.height)` and check what happening, to access the console, press F12 in the browser window and go to console tab!

Comment: @JohnAuer learning JavaScript can be tough, if you ever get stuck on anything feel free to give me a shout and I'll try and help you out